# Create Table with a columns is a sum from values from other tables

Tags: powerbi

I'm "bugging" to transform my datas to something usable.
For the moment, a datasource provides me a table where a column contains dates, following by 24 columns representing each hours. In this 24 columns, for each date (each row) I've a total of phone calls.

[image]

I want to show the hourly repartition. So, my original datasource is not really usable ans need to transform it with something where there is a column "hour"  (a simple index from 0 to 23 or 1 to 24)  and a column with the total call for each column from the original column.   But I'm a lot confused to do it because I don't have a way to create a relationship. Like this :

[image]

Someone have any idea to help me?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [unpivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) the data source and then create two dimensions (Calendar) and (Time).